# Unable to find cell when cell is merged

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Find function to looking for "apple" cell, it work nice when the "apple" cell is not merged with other cells

```
Cells.Find("apple")
```

My Question is I can't find the "apple" cell when it is merged. I tried following if statement but it keep returns *"not found"*. Any answer is appreciate.

```
Set obj = Cells.Find("apple")
If obj Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Not found"
End If
```

---

**Updated at 2014/02/17 15:30JST**

I found the problems, I guess maybe it is bugs.
If the cell merged contain cell at "A1", "apple" cell unable to be found. "apple" cell can be found when it didn't merged with "A1" cell.

"apple" cell can be found

[image]

"apple" cell cannot be found

[image]

---

**Updated at 2014/02/17 16:00JST**

I have solved the problems above by adding option

```
Find("apple", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
```

Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the other options for Find.  Settings persist from the previous us.

Comment: I tried and it works. Are you sure it's not because of other issues?

Comment: Yes, @TimWilliams is correct. the `.Find` always remembers the last setting. This is beneficial especially if you have to repeatedly use `.Find` or using `.FindNext`. Your code for example may not work if the cell has `APPLE` or `APple` oe `aPPle` if the `MatchCase:=True` and hence you should always explicitly specify the parameters of `.Find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple other options you can pass to `Find()`, apart from the first "what to look for" argument.

If you only pass the first, you may get behaviour which is different from what you expect, particularly if you've previously used `Find()` and set one or more of the parameters: those settings persist across calls and will affect later uses of Find().

For this reason it's good practice to always pass the other parameters along with the first one.

Comment: Ya, you are right. I solved this problems by adding option `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious`. Thank you so much.